# Can I draw a rectangle in GtkWindow directly without GtkDrawingArea?

Tags: gtk

1、I have looked up many references about drawing a rectangle in GtkWindow in Gtk,but lots of them are used GtkDrawingArea . I want to know that can I  draw a rectangle in GtkWindow  directly without GtkDrawingArea?And if i can do this ,how should i do? Is there any examples or references?

2、Actually, I need to draw a rectangle in a gtkwindow ,and then add two buttons in the rectangle and  specify coordinates of the point set to the fixed color value in a small field in the rectangle.
   I have tried the way of drawing rectangle by GtkDrawingArea,but GtkDrawingArea isn't a GTK_CONTAINER ,so I can't add anything in GtkDrawingArea;I also tried to use some Layout managers such as gtk_vbox ,but it seems failed. I can't place a button in the area of the rectangle.

Now I am confused how to do next.If someone can give me some guide or reference ,Thank you for much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You may need to set the "app-paintable" flag on the `GtkWindow`, but you can connect to its `draw` signal, and draw on the background with Cairo. Then return `FALSE` from the `draw` signal handler to signify that other handlers should still be invoked for the drawing; then the buttons can still be drawn on top. I don't know of any online examples for drawing directly on the window, though.

Comment: Thank you very much!As you said,I have done this with setting the "app-paintable" flag.But it seems that the drawing operation must be done in the draw signal handler.Now I need to show an image on a small  field in the rectangle which i drawed directly above by setting the colour value of the points which specified by coordinates. So I must draw on the small field frequenty.I know I have two methods:

Comment: 1、connect different draw signal handers to do this . But First ,I am not sure  weather I can do like this ,and if I can   ,how gtk will done with many signal handlers; 2、Manually emit the draw signal when i need to redraw.If this method is avaliable,what shall I do next?can you give me some detailed guides? Thank you very much!

Comment: It's no problem to connect more than one signal handler. And if you need to trigger an emission of the `draw` signal, then use `gtk_widget_queue_draw()`. Unfortunately I can't give you a detailed guide without knowing what it is exactly that you are doing.